# C# string.split issue with my code

Tags: c#, string, split

I am writing some code to scramble words. This is a 2nd attempt using a different method `string.split (' ')`.

I am unable to get the output from the code below that i want.

what i am trying to do with the code is take a string from the console.readline and then split it and remove any spaces and then output this to the console.write. (test is there just so i could see the for loop was working)

so

```
input: 1 2 3 4
should be 
output:
1
2
3
4
....



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string input = Console.ReadLine();
       string[] words = input.Split(' ');
        words = new string[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }     
    }
}
```

}

input: 1 2 3 4 5 ...... (just as a test)

Output: 
(blank)
test

test

test

test

... ect

any help with getting the split working would be great

Comment: string[] words = input.Split(' '); 
        words = new string[10];

this makes no sense... you overwrite what split gave you

Answer (score 8):

This is the problem:

```
string[] words = input.Split(' ');
words = new string[10];
```

You're using `Split`... and then completely ignoring the result, by assigning a new value to the variable. The overall result (ignoring any possible exceptions) is the same as if you'd just written:

```
string[] words = new string[10];
```

... i.e. an array of 10 null references.

It's also unclear why you're then *reading* from the console again in the loop.

Comment: thank you so much... i'v been looking at the code without spotting that mistake... this is due to me taking the complete code i was using last night and rewriting it to use the .split.

Answer (score 3):

```
   string[] words = input.Split(' ');
    words = new string[10];
```

You are overwriting `words` immediately with an empty array.

`string.split` creates the array for you. Remove the second line and your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below could should work fine.

```
class Program
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {      
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  string[] words = new string[10];
  words = input.Split(' ');
  for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
  {            
   Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
   Console.WriteLine("test");
  }   
  Console.ReadKey();
 }
}
```

If you dont want to specify the limit of the array form before then

```
string[] words = input.Split(' ');
```

will also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try foreach instead of for

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         string input = Console.ReadLine();
         string[] words = input.Split(' ');

         foreach (string word in words)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(word);
              Console.WriteLine("test");
         }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take out the second init of the words array:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string input = Console.ReadLine();
       string[] words = input.Split(' ');
//        words = new string[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] words = input.Split(' ');
       // words = new string[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write(words[i]);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
 }
```